# Writing commands on linux terminal using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get Qt creator to print a user input by using a push button on an UI into the terminal. As of now, the code is executable on the terminal via human input. Here is the code:

```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess::execute("/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");

    system("cd catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");
    system("./submodbus_node");

}
```

Current output when using the code

[image]

Output via human input

[image]

The versions i'm running on are:
-Ubuntu 16.04
-QT Creator 3.5.1

Comment: change `cd catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus` to `cd /full_path/of/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no it still says not found

Comment: remove `system("cd catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");
    system("./submodbus_node");` and change `QProcess::execute("/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");` to `QProcess::execute("/full/path/of/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus/submodbus_node");`

Comment: This exe file is for a robot operation and I am currently using the executable file named submodbus_node from here [link](https://imgur.com/a/mnmJLXp)
but trying to open it directly from here does not do anything, i have to source its location and type ./submodbus node into the console to actually run this exe file.
I have tried what you suggested above but there were no results

Comment: Are you trying to change the working directory first then execute the program?

Answer (score 3):

`system` can't change the current directory globally. but could use like this:

```
system("cd /catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus && ./submodbus_node");
```

or using [QProcess::setProgram](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProgram) with [QProcess::setWorkingDirectory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory)

```
QProcess p;
p.setProgram("submodbus_node");
//p.setArguments(QStringList()<<args); // if you need
p.setWorkingDirectory("/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");
p.start();
```

or [QDir::setCurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setCurrent)

```
QDir::setCurrent("/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus");
QProcess::startDetached("submodbus_node");
```

---

Test demo, create three files in the parent directory:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    system("cd ../ && touch test1.txt");

    QProcess p;
    p.setProgram("touch");
    p.setArguments(QStringList()<<"test2.txt");
    p.setWorkingDirectory("../");
    p.start();

    QDir::setCurrent("../");
    QProcess::startDetached("touch test3.txt");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried your second method and found out that there is no member called setProgram in QProcess

Comment: @AvremTan What's the Qt version? (not QtCreator). the second one requires Qt 5.1.

Comment: I'm running it on Qt version 5.5.1

Comment: @AvremTan umm...that's weird. I am using the environment exactly same as you. What's the error message?

Comment: @AvremTan Could you post the line where you invoke the function?

Comment: [I have made some minor changes to your code](https://imgur.com/a/ngVdJYx)

Comment: @AvremTan Sorry, can't find where is wrong, the code looks fine for me. You could use the other two solutions.

Comment: For your first solution, i received a similar error to previously saying it cannot be found
For your third solution, i received this [error message](https://imgur.com/a/wY7uxFb)

Comment: @AvremTan Sorry I fixed the third one, Could you try to make an empty project and copy the test demo, it will create three files in the parent directory. BTW in the first one, `system` function cannot be found?

Comment: [This is the error for the first one](https://imgur.com/a/MXZRT9x)
[I created a new project but still recieved the same error](https://imgur.com/a/fh4zrkz)

Comment: @AvremTan The first one looks like you miss a space after `cd`. it was a typo in the third one, I changed `start` to `startDetached`.

Comment: For the first one i changed the typo and now it says i [cannot cd](https://imgur.com/a/6lPcPrE)
For the third one, Error remains the [same](https://imgur.com/a/yCNk3In)

Comment: @AvremTan change the path to `/home/your user name/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus`

Comment: I tried, in my case my username is ros so i did /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/submodbus but it still says i cannot cd

Comment: @AvremTan Not familiar with ROS...looks like .bashrc cannot apply the change immediately in the current terminal, have to start a new one.